# D3 Display elements of inner list on tool tip as different lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

A quick and short question in d3. I have the following data in json:

```
{"KMAE":[-120.12,36.98,"MADERA MUNICIPAL AIRPORT",[26,1,2,5,6,3,2,1,2,7,29,12,3]]}
```

I am plotting this point on a google map and applying a tool tip on the point. On the tool tip what I have given now is

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
        div .html(d.value[3])
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
```

Well what now I am getting when mouse over happens is 26,1,2,5,6,3,2,1,2,7,29,12,3.

How can we make this in different lines inside the tool tip? Say like:
26 on top, 1 below that, 2 below that and so on.
In my actual application this inner list's length wont be the same for many points like KMAE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using HTMl for the tooltip, it's easy -- join the array elements with `<br>`:

```
div.html(d.value[3].join("<br>"))
```

Comment: Thats cool..I was thinking about inner iterations like in python..Thanks a lot

Comment: and one more small question: Can we dynamically adjust the size of a tool tip according to the length of this inner list

Comment: any comments on this?

Comment: Well if it's a `div` it should do that automatically unless you're setting a size explicitly.